# Pfsense + Cincinnati Bell Fioptics IPTV

Tags: networking, pfsense, iptv, igmp

Recently signed up for Cincinnati Bell Fioptics FTTH with IPTV. Replaced the provided wireless router with a pfsense box + Ubiquiti AP and the internet works great. However, I cannot get the IPTV boxes to work. I've read every post the internet has about Fioptics IPTV networking, and many posts from @Mech, with no luck.

Here's what I have:

pfsense 2.5.2-RELEASE

IGMP enabled, WAN upstream 10.0.0.0/8, LAN downstream 239.0.0.0/8

[image: screenshot]

IGMP WAN pass rule, UDP IPTV traffic pass

[image: screenshot]

IGMP LAN pass rule

[image: screenshot]

All rules have the "Allow packets with IP options to pass" box checked. In the Firewall System Logs I see IGMP traffic matches on both WAN and LAN, suggesting that IGMP traffic is flowing successfully, but not the actual multicast traffic.

Only one WAN interface and one LAN interface. No vlans, PPPoE, or anything fancy like that.

As part of my debugging, I set up two of the ports on the pfsense box as a bridge and connected the ISP provided router through them in order to capture the traffic. I set the bridge as an interface, created a "pass all IPV4" rule, and enabled the "Allow packets with IP options to bass" box, at which point the TV started working. Capturing the traffic confirmed that all Fioptics IPTV streams originate from 10.0.0.0/8 and are destined for 239.0.0.0/8 as suggested [here in this “Fioptics (IPTV by Cincinnati Bell) Definitive Guide”](https://community.ui.com/questions/Fioptics-IPTV-by-Cincinnati-Bell-Definitive-Guide/63250775-e096-4d0f-a096-e41e461c6d11).

Wireshark capture

[image: screenshot]

I tried to make rules in the bridge interface to match the IPTV traffic specifically (IPv4 UDP from 10.0.0.0/8), but could not get the rules to match any traffic even though I could see it in Packet Capture. This suggests to me that the packets were being routed at the link layer and not the firewall due to the bridge.

I also made sure I am using the ISP DNS servers to eliminate that as a possible issue.

Does anyone have any ideas? Spitballing: Do I need to add more networks to the IGMP proxy? Are my pass-through rules not adequate? Is my box dropping all link-layer multicast packets at the interface so they never even get to the firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it working and am successfully watching the Fioptics IPTV right now thru the pfsense router. There were two problems - one change to the configuration shown in the question, and another I discovered separately.

First problem: 224.0.0.0/8 needs to be added to the IGMP proxy downstream, like this:
[image]
Interesting note: 239 is 11101111 and 224 is 11100000, so these are both under a 224.0.0.0/4 mask. I do see some IGMP packets destined for 225.x.x.x (11100001) - so I wonder if 224.0.0.0/4 is actually the "more correct" downstream IGMP network.

Second problem: DNS. In order to isolate all traffic to/from the IPTV box, I set up a second LAN port (called IPTV), and switched only the IPTV box over to it. Capturing the traffic revealed that the first thing the box does when it boots is a DNS query for entm.iptv.zoomtown.com (and then a series of others sequentially after each one resolves successfully).

I had configured pfsense originally to use 1.1.1.1 as the DNS server, which does not resolve that hostname. Then, I allowed the ISP DHCP to configure the DNS servers but the default ones provided also would not resolve that name. Only the DNS servers ns1.fuse.net (216.68.1.100) and ns2.fuse.net (216.68.2.100) will resolve them. These must have been configured on the ISP provided router. I did not want all DNS queries to go to these servers however, so I re-configured the DNS servers under General Setup to be 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1, then set the DHCP DNS servers for the IPTV interface (Services -> DHCP Server -> IPTV) to the two fuse servers. That seemed to fix it.

Update Jan 1 22:

Cincinnati Bell has been making some changes. It is now necessary to include 172.16.0.0/12 in your IGMP proxy. I have not investigated if 10/8 is still required. They made the first changes roughly two weeks ago and I added 172.0.0.0/8 to the IGMP, which worked until now, at which point the /12 version is necessary, which is the full 172.16.x.x private IPV4 address space. Note I also switched the downstream to 224/4.

[image]

Update Jan 17 22:

The game of cat-and-mouse continues. Had to add 172.17.0.0/16 to the IGMP proxy. This is a subset of 172.16/12, so I'm not sure why yet, but it works again.

[image]

Update July 8 22:

Turns out the IGMP settings are correct at 224.0.0.0/4. The problem was the IGMP proxy service crashing. It seems to have something to do with the Fioptics IPTV multicast packets themselves. The "fix" is to install the Service Watchdog plugin to auto-restart the igmpproxy service when it crashes. Mystery solved!

Comment: No, the domain is properly delegated to those two servers, and resolves worldwide. I'm pretty sure it doesn't resolve for you because of the "DNS rebinding protection" option in pfsense which deliberately blocks DNS responses that resolve to "internal" IP addresses. That said, Unbound (the "DNS Resolver" in pfsense) as well as Dnsmasq support using domain-specific DNS servers if needed.

Comment: Interesting... What would be the "best" way to address this? The options I can see are: 1) leave the DNS servers configured in the DHCP server for the interface. 2) use domain-specific DNS servers. 3) Disable DNS rebinding protection for the domain via custom option.